# Help to amend existing JSON to add a vertical align element

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, json-formatting, column-formatting

I currently have the JSON formatting applied to a column:

```
{
  "$schema": "developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/…",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', '•')",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Not Due', 'green', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'OverDue', 'red', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Approaching','yellow','white')))",
    "font-size": "2.5em"
  }
}
```

I want to add a component to align the text in the column to the vertical middle of the cell, something like:

```
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle"
```

Can anyone help me to combine these two elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the JSON formatting as below.

```
{ 
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div", 
    "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', @currentField, '• '+@currentField)", 
    "style": { 
        "color": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Not Due', 'green', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'OverDue', 'red', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Approaching','yellow','white')))",
        "font-size": "2.5em",
        "display": "table-cell",
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle"
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering `@currentField` in your second JSON is the value of **Review Status** as you need.

Try using below JSON Code:

**If you want colored Text**:

```
{ 
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div", 
    "style": {
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "color": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Not Due', 'green', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'OverDue', 'red', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Approaching','yellow','white')))"
    },
    "children": [
    {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', '• '",
        "style": {
            "font-size": "2.5em"
        }
    },
    {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', [$Review_x0020_Status]"
    }]
}
```

**If you want default color of list to Text**:

```
{ 
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div", 
    "style": {
        "text-align": "center",
        "vertical-align": "middle"
    },
    "children": [
    {
        "elmType": "span",
        "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', '• '",
        "style": {
            "color": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Not Due', 'green', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'OverDue', 'red', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Approaching','yellow','white')))",
            "font-size": "2.5em"
        }
    },
    {
        "elmType": "span",
        "style": {
            "color": "#666666"
        },
        "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', [$Review_x0020_Status]"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi, any update on this? Is it working for you? If Yes, please [accept this as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that this question will not be shown in Unanswered questions,